# How to resize font in plot_net feature of phyloseq?

Tags: ggplot2, rstudio, phyloseq

I want to resize my text in plot_net but none of the options are working for me. I am trying

```
p <- plot_net(physeqP, maxdist = 0.4, point_label = "ID", color = "Cond", shape = "Timeperiod") p + geom_text(size=15)
```

This gives me error

> "Error: geom_text requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y,
>   label".

Can anyone please tell me how can I fix the issue?

I dont want to resize legends or the axis, but the nodes text.

[this image is drawn using phyloseq but since the font size is very small, i want to make it prominent.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhAfP.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without an example it's hard to reproduce.

```
p <- plot_net(physeqP, maxdist = 0.4, point_label = "ID"
     , color = "Cond", shape = "Timeperiod", cex_val  = 2)
```

I believe this is with the NeuralNetTools package.

Try using: **cex_val** numeric value indicating size of text labels, **default 1**

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/NeuralNetTools/versions/1.5.0/topics/plotnet

Comment: Hi! thank you for the answer... Here you can see the example actually.

https://joey711.github.io/phyloseq/plot_network-examples.html